# A problem on analytic functions and identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following problem (I have tried to solve it by Identity theorem but "answers"(="options") are confusing.

> Let $f$ be analytic function on a bounded domain $D$ such that $f(z)=f(2z)$ for all $z\in D$. Then (which of the following is/are true?)
>
> (1) $f$ is non-zero constant.
>
> (2) $f$ is identity function.
>
> (3) $f$ is identically zero on $D$.
>
> (4) $f$ is not identically zero on $D$.

Confusion is the following. Suppose we take a disk $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with the following property:

> Whenever $z$ is in $D$ then $2z\notin D$ and $\frac{z}{2}\notin D$.

Such discs can be easily obtained: take a disk of radius say $\frac{1}{10}$ in upper half plane far above from $x$-axis.

Clearly $D$ is a bounded domain. Let $f$ be any analytic function on $D$.

Since there is no $z\in D$ such that $2z\in D$ or $\frac{z}{2}\in D$.

In other words, no $z\in D$ violates the property of $f$; but for this $f$, no option among (1) to (4) can be definitely chosen. So, no option is correct. Am I right?

Else, where is mistake? Is it in my understanding or question?

Comment: The question is badly formulated.

Comment: Agreed, I share your confusion.

Comment: @mrf: which question you mean? The problem posed in yellow-background or the question posed after it?

Comment: The yellow-background posed one. We have to put some conditions on $D$ for it to make sense, for example that $\{ z \in D : 2z \in D \}$ contains an open non-empty set (or at least a set containing accumulation points in $D$).

Comment: yes; there was no condition on $D$; a similar kind of question has been appeared http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666857/let-f-mathbbc-rightarrow-mathbbc-be-a-continuous-function-and-assume here in which $D=\mathbb{C}$, but this is not a bounded domain then. I was feeling that the *multiple choice question* is incorrect.

Comment: Your argument is correct. Check whether there are additional conditions on $D$ in the original formulation of the problem.